# Updating Field in Django does not work

Tags: python, django, forms, field

I have the following in my views.py

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form = ExtraForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
    print ("hi")
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print ("yes")
    print ("newform is ")
else:
    form = ExtraForm(instance=request.user)
    context['form']=form
return render(request, "updateProfile.html",context)
```

Now what happens is that I get no errors and it does everything perfectly fine but it does NOT end up updating anything!! Which does not make sense to me. Any idea what is going on?

ExtraForm:

```
class ExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    research_place = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    studies = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))

    class Meta:
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = ['research_place','studies']
        widgets = {
            # 'image': ImageCropWidget,
        }
```

Models:

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    biography = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    research_place = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)
    studies = models.CharField(max_length=1000000,blank=True)

    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='uploaded_images',default ="uploaded_images/defaultReal.jpg")
    # cropping = ImageRatioField('image','200x200',size_warning=True) #width x height

    avatar_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                    processors=[ResizeToFill(200, 200)],
                                    format='JPEG',
                                    options={'quality': 60})

    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("has_uploaded", ("Has uploaded")),
            ("is_authenticated", ("Is authenticated")),
        )
```

Comment: What do you return when form is valid? What's the value of `context` in that case?

Comment: @ozgur i don't have anything in context, but when i check the database the change hasn't gone through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the form is not valid at all. Add an `else` clause and check for [errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ExtraForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # You should perform some redirection here btw.
        return redirect("/success/")
    else:
        print "Errors:", form.errors
        context["form"] = form
else:
    form = ExtraForm(instance=request.user)
    context["form"] = form
return render(request, "updateProfile.html", context)
```

After update:

You are passing the wrong user to form. `request.user` is `User` type whereas you try updating `RegisteredUser`. You should update the line:

```
form = ExtraForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
```

to

```
form = ExtraForm(request.POST, instance=RegisteredUser.objects.get(user=request.user))
```

Same applies to `else` part too:

```
form = ExtraForm(instance=RegisteredUser.objects.get(user=request.user))
```

Comment: No there are no errors, it works just fine. It print ("success") works after form.save()

Comment: 1. Did you override `save` method of the form? 2. Did you by any chance call save with `commit=False`? 3. Did you try the above code? 4. Can you also show us `ExtraForm` class? 5. Is this the entire code in the view function or just a part of it?